# Using client-customized resources (resx) as well as default resources

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resources, resx

I'm trying to find info on how best to allow localization and client-customization of resource files.

It will be simple to give a demo, but first what I am doing: We have an app that is a product, but we allow clients to customize that product.

What I want (I think) is to create out product with a message "Welcome" (English) and "Welkom" (Afrikaans). The product needs to support different languages.

But, the client is allowed to change "Welcome" to "Hey Again" in the English resources.

However we release an update (say v2) and we add a new key "Bye" to the resources.

What is the best practice to prevent overriding the client's customizations, but update the default resources so that it is now at the latest version with both keys?

In pseudo-code:

```
Load default resources (English) - this is done by .NET
Load default regional resources (Afrikaans) - this is done by .NET
Load the client resources (English) - ?
Load the client regional resources (Afrikaans) - ?
```

Thus, the final request for "Bye" in any language returns "Bye" (new), but the final request for "Welcome" in English returns "Hey Again" (client) and "Welkom" (default) in Afrikaans.

Comment: I've been working on exactly same project. Default language, additional language and in each, client can customize the string. Well, my solution was - database. Each field had a key. this key would be used in combination with language. Imagine a table with key, languageId, defaultString, customString. You have the key and the language selected by user. Then you can run updates using db scripts. You will not overwrite custom strings or entire custom records. But your key+language combination will be static.

Comment: I agree in part, but see my comment to @Remy

Answer (score 1):

As T.S. mentioned above, I would also recommend a database resource provider.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

Depending on your application, you can use the standard MS SQL Resource provider or customize it in case it's an app where MS SQL makes no sense.

Comment: What if the product is separate from a database? Such as a front end for a logic engine? The app itself does not use a database, but communicates via an API to an existing system, its no use introducing an enter database dependency for *simple" localization.

Comment: Since you need flexibility resource files don't provide and DB is too much because you don't use thousand of strings in your client application, you can create local database. It can be a file in which you serialize a datatable and you can have same logic as if you worked against large database. Then, you will need a tool to create and edit this file.